# Real Time Cluster Log Delivery in a Databricks Cluster

Tags: python, logging, databricks, azure-databricks, near-real-time

I have some Python code that I am running on a Databricks Job Cluster. My Python code will be generating a whole bunch of logs and I want to be able to monitor these logs in real time (or near real time), say through something like a dashboard.

What I have done so far is, I have configured my cluster log delivery location and my logs are delivered to the specified destination every 5 minutes.

This is explained here,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure

Here is an extract from the same article,

> When you create a cluster, you can specify a location to deliver the
> logs for the Spark driver node, worker nodes, and events. Logs are
> delivered every five minutes to your chosen destination. When a
> cluster is terminated, Azure Databricks guarantees to deliver all logs
> generated up until the cluster was terminated.

Is there some way I can have these logs delivered somewhere in near real time, rather than every 5 minutes? It does not have to be through the same method either, I am open to other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in below screenshot by default it is 5 minutes. Unfortunately, it cannot be changed. There is no information given in [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#cluster-log-delivery).

[image]

However, you can raise feature request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/2efba7dc-ef24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0)